# WordPress website too slow in Google App Engine & Cloud SQL

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I just created a WordPress website using Google App Engine for PHP and Cloud SQL service for MySQL back-end. It doesn't have large content. It just starter website with buddypress. But **it's too slow to load a webpage on first-time.** Since am using some recommended cache plugins it's pretty decent on repeated page hits.

I almost tried everything recommended. But still it's slow. Can you please anyone give me a solution.

Already cloud sql server is on preferred location of app engine only.

Is Google App Engine & Cloud SQL combo not good for WordPress?

Comment: May I ask your Cloud SQL instance region? I've heard some asia regions of Cloud SQL not working well with Google App Engine these days.

Comment: FWIW, App Engine + Google Cloud SQL is slow for us too, the database seems to have very high response times.

Comment: I want to comment but not allowed because my reputation still low. Btw I believe it's because we need to have memory cache. That's means we need to use another Google Cloud service like Memorystore since app engine is read only.

Answer (score -2):

Check that your instance is always on (both for App Engine and Cloud SQL). If not, it takes time to spin up your resources after the application has been dormant and spun down.

Note that always on instances incur a slightly higher price that on demand instances.

Hope this helps!